# Is there any service by which to simulate a dynamic IP while using a static?

Tags: dynamic, ip

My company has a service we need to test with dynamic IPs as our clients have ISPs which switch their IPs semi-often but I only have access to static IP testing. I've looked around but can't find any way to simulate a dynamic IP. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you create a VM with a cloud provider (e.g. Google Cloud, AWS, Digital Ocean etc) you will get a new IP address.  You can therefore use that to your benefit to create, test, then destroy VMs quickly each with a new IP address.